# How to know if SQL alias is used or Server is used in sharepoint if both are same

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sql-server

I have a situation where SQL server name is SQLABC and SQLAlias is configured on SharePoint server with same name SQLABC. So in Cliconfig.exe we see below in the fields:

SQL Alias: SQLABC
Server Name: SQLABC

While configuring SharePoint SQLABC was used everything is working fine. Now as we require high availability we have another SQL server and created an AGListener (AGLISTENER).

Now we want SharePoint to respond to the listener and not to single server, so we are updating all the other aspects as per MS documentation but want to keep the same Alias name and just update the listener. Below is new configuration required.

SQL Alias: SQLABC
Server Name: AGLISTENER

Now we want to understand what is used by SharePoint, if Alias is used then we are good to go by updating Server name in Cliconfig. But if SharePoint is pointing to the Database Server, we will need to update all the databases to point to SQLAlias. How can this be done if SharePoint is already referring to same name, how will it understand to point to Alias and not the server.

Any help is greatly Appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If SQL alias is available to SharePoint, it will use SQL alias. If there is no alias configured on the SharePoint Server, it will try to connect to DB by using SQL server name.

In my experience, when we upgraded SQL database server for an existing SharePoint 2013 farm where originally SQL alias was not configured, we just **created SQL alias** with the **same name as the original SQL Instance Name** to move the DBs to new server.